# Why Devise change me the sender name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, gmail, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I have created a google account and so a Gmail account (as example we consider: mytest@gmail.com) to send emails by my application. The account settings have the sender name "MyTest" and if i try to send a message normally, the MailBox of the recipient presents a message from "MyTest" (sender name). But if I send an email by my application, in which i make the access by smtp into gmail with this account, the MailBox of the recipient presents a message from "mytest@gmail.com"...how it is possible?

> *config/initializers/devise.rb*

```
config.mailer_sender = 'MyTest'
```

> *config/environments/development.rb*

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    user_name:      'mytest@gmail.com',
    password:       'passwordtest',
    domain:         'localhost:3000',
    address:       'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:          '587',
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's about the format, you need to add it in this way in the devise initializer

```
config.mailer_sender = '"MyTest" <mytest@gmail.com>'
```